# ngOnChanges only triggered by data binding?

Tags: angular, onchange

Having this plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/litwgoJ1OLbnHNjIIYhO

Why is this not working?

Why is `ngOnChanges` not fired, if from the parent I change manually a property without any data binding, and then call the `ChangeDetector.markForCheck()`?

Is there any workaround without having to implement my own DoCheck() ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `ngOnChanges` are for inputs only

Comment: that is an input, isnt it?

Comment: You have an input, but you are not binding anything to that

Comment: I know, but just flagging a property with the annotation I believe should be enough for the CD to go and check it. If this is the intended behavior, fine (it should be better documented I think, but fine), but if it is not.... why?

Comment: But it documented: "Angular calls its **ngOnChanges** method whenever it detects changes to **input properties** of the component (or directive)." It checks for changes when you bind, if your **AppComponent** had a property `fatherProp` and you pass it to your child, by doing this, <child [fatherProp]=['prop']></child>`  ngOnchanges would only be called if `fatherProp` changes. Doing `child.prop` won't trigger a change

Comment: right, fair enough, thanks!

Comment: @FabioAntunes you'll add this as answer, it'll help others